# Create nested divs which are draggable inside their parent div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Initially app will have only one thing that is a button `AddParent` on the top.

`AddParent` button will add a parent Draggable to this component i.e every time the user clicks the AddParent button, a parent draggable should envelope the draggable component. Keep in mind that each level of component should in itself be draggable inside its parents’ window i.e. each of the title bars can be used to move around the respective component inside its parents’ blank box.
Something like this (after 3 clicks of AddParent, there are 3 parents for the initial child) ->
(You don’t need to actually color the blank areas, it is just for ease of explanation...they can be white)
result after 3 clicks - [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gw2FM.jpg)

Goal is to achive [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q-iIEKaypmNUQUdlQkOlytWjjFo1GO1K/view)

I have tried a lot but not able to come with expected solution. This is working but it is dragging its parent component too and top-most component is not draggble to bottom side.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Draggable from 'react-draggable';

function ParentDraggable(props) {
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);
  const [y, setY] = useState(0);
  

  const handleMouseDown = (e) => {
    let startX = e.clientX;
    let startY = e.clientY;

    const handleMouseMove = (e) => {
      setX(x + e.clientX - startX);
      setY(y + e.clientY - startY);
      startX = e.clientX;
      startY = e.clientY;
    };

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    });
  };

  return (
    <Draggable bounds='parent' handle='.handle'>
    <div
      style={{
        position: 'relative',
        top: y,
        left: x,
        border: '1px solid black',
        width: `${props.w}px`,
        height: `${props.w}px`,
      }}
    >
      <div
        style={{
          height: 20,
          backgroundColor: 'gray',
        }}
        onMouseDown={handleMouseDown}
        className='handle'
        onClick={e=>e.preventDefault()}
      >
        Title Bar
      </div>
      {props.children}
    </div>
    </Draggable>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [parents, setParents] = useState([]);
  const [w, setW] = useState(200)

  const handleAddParent = () => {
    setParents([ <ParentDraggable w = {w}>
     {parents}
    </ParentDraggable>]);
    setW(prev => prev + 200)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleAddParent}>AddParent</button>
      {parents}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you want to check code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-smoke-erw0tt?file=/src/App.js)

Please help me to achieve my [goal](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q-iIEKaypmNUQUdlQkOlytWjjFo1GO1K/view)

Answer (score 0):

I've defined a component for the draggable element, called `DraggableThing`.

```
// Since the thing being dragged can be both a child and a parent,
// I've avoided using either or those terms in the name of the component.
// Hence why it's poorly named Draggable "thing".
function DraggableThing({ children, elementNo }) {
  return (
    <Draggable
      bounds="parent" // only want to move this element within the parent bounds
      handle=".drag-bar" // only want to drag on the red bar
      onStart={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} // be sure to stop event propagation
    >
      <div
        className='box'
        style={{ width: 100 * elementNo, height: 100 * elementNo }}
      >
        <div className="drag-bar">{`Click ${elementNo}`}</div>
        {children}
      </div>
    </Draggable>
  );
}
```

The `App` component is responsible for rendering the initial draggable element and adding parents to it.

```
function App() {
  // Keep track of the element count so we can
  // determine the title of each draggable item
  const elementCount = useRef(1);

  // Hold the top-most draggable element in state.
  // When adding a new parent, it becomes our new top-most
  // element, and the previous top most element becomes it's children
  const [topElement, setTopElement] = useState(
    <DraggableThing elementNo={elementCount.current} />
  );

  // Add the parent as the new top-most element
  function addParent() {
    setTopElement(
      <DraggableThing elementNo={++elementCount.current}>
        {topElement}
      </DraggableThing>
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addParent}>Add Parent</button>
      {topElement}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the styles are as follows.

```css
#root {
  height: 100dvh;
  width: 100dvw;
}

.App {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px;
}

.drag-bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```